# textBox1_Enter in wpf

Tags: wpf, events

What is the equivalent Following code in wpf

code in winapp :

```
 private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Enter` event on a WPF textbox - you could use the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) event to the same effect though.

```
private void textbox1_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

this is accessed in the XAML as follows:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="textbox1_GotFocus"/>
```